# iphone development - saving data UI

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

What is the easiest and simplest way to save a string so that you can use it later on. (DATA persistance)

I've heard of property lists, SQlite3 ..

Comment: It depends on what you're going to need to do with the string later. There are many ways, including Core Data, NSUserDefaults, plists, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NSUSerDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the easiest and simplest:

```
// To save...
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"my string" forKey:@"someKey"];

// To retrieve...
NSString* recoveredString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"someKey"];
```

Comment: Don't forget to synchronize when you save with [NSUserDefaults synchronize];

Comment: @jabroni, synchronize isn't a lightweight method. The documentation says that you should only use it if you cannot wait for automatic synchronization.  Since it's more context specific, I opted to omit it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something really simple, try NSUserDefaults

```
-(void)saveToUserDefaults:(NSString*)myString
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"Prefs"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
}

-(NSString*)retrieveFromUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *val = nil;

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Prefs"];

    return val;
}
```

Please keep in mind, you don't want to be storing a ton of data this way, but if it is a simple string that you need to set and get back, it will get the job done.

Comment: This works as well, but I tend to use it more for preferences and "hidden" things than anything else.

Comment: what if i have more than one strings? (i'm still new at this)

Comment: You can still do it.  The "Pref" is the name of your key that you are saving.  So if you have String1 and String2, you can set them like so.
 
[standardUserDefaults setObject:@"String1Value" forKey:@"String1Key"]; 
[standardUserDefaults setObject:@"String2Value" forKey:@"String2Key"];  

You can retrieve these values using the keys you created them with.

Comment: thank you. But does this work if i want to save a string in one UIViewController and retrieve it in another one?

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve the data from the NSUserDefaults in different views in you project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you're going to need to do with it later. I recommend Core Data, to be honest. It may be overweight for what you need, but it is fairly easy once you figure it all out.